# How can I optimize galley space utilization?

Tags: aircraft-design

I am working on a project aimed at improving the galley (inserts) of a commercial aircraft. My focus is on "[image: How can I optimize galley space utilization?]" I have discovered that the galley often takes on a U-shape design, and the corners tend to be underutilized due to limited accessibility. Some aircraft have trash compactors placed in the corners, but this significantly adds to the aircraft's weight, making it an unsustainable solution. Additionally, there is often insufficient space for waste storage in the aircraft, as waste is typically disposed of in bags, which consumes a significant amount of space. Ideally, waste should be efficiently and quickly sorted to minimize space usage and facilitate recycling. And at the same time it would be nice to also compact the waste.

I am seeking information on practical construction plans and dimensions for the galley, highlighting unused spaces. Additionally, any knowledge on the weight of aircraft trash compactor components would be valuable. Any other tips, insights or ideas related to optimizing galley space utilization are also welcome.

Comment: Where did you try to find the answers yourself? It seems there is some literature on galley design already, perhaps you could consult those.

Comment: Wide open "*how might I design this thing better*" questions aren't a good fit here.

Comment: As usual, optimisation is always a compromise between different factors. While trash volume might be a problem, separating the trash also takes up both space (for sorting and later storing in different containers) and valuable time for the crew.

Comment: Note: on airplane the weight is more important then space (e.g. for a compactor), also separate waste takes time (on short/medium haul we do not have it; on long haul there is also rest period). Corner spaces: sinks (so you do not need to access water collector), and electrical cabinet can be placed). Check youbute videos of cabin crew to get an idea on what they need (and the little trick that they use: which may be solved in a better way). Space optimization is probably not so important.